# I'm getting weird errors for seemingly simple Java code. What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: java, constructor

I have a final project for my introduction to software class that is split into parts. For the first part, here are the instructions:

> Task 1-1:
>   Create a Class called Inventory
>
> 1. Consisting of three data members: a part number consisting of 2 letters followed by four numbers (e.g. AB1234), a description
>      consisting of 5-25 letters describing the item (e.g. wooden
>      claw-hammer), and a quantity consisting of an integer between 0 and
>      1000.
> 2. Create a default constructor that sets the part number to AA0000, the description to Test Item, and the quantity to zero.
> 3. Create a parameterized constructor that sets the part number, description, and quantity to argument values sent to the constructor.
> 4. Create set methods for each data member that changes the value of the member to the argument passed to the method. Also create a group
>      of get methods that retrieve each data member.
> 5. Create a method called show part that displays the formatted contents of an object.

Seems simple, yeah? Well obviously I'm doing something wrong but I'm not exactly sure what, could be a minor error or maybe I just don't know what I'm doing somehow. I've tried removing the constructors and certain methods (`showPart()` in particular) whilst getting the same or similar errors.

Here's my code:

```
public class InventoryFinal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String partNo;
        String prodDesc;
        int quantity;

        public InventoryFinal() {
            partNo = "AA0000";
            prodDesc = "Test Item";
            quantity = 0;
        }

        public InventoryFinal(String s, String s2, int i) {
            partNo = s;
            prodDesc = s2;
            quantity = i;
        }

        public void setPartNo(String sSet) {
            partNo = sSet;
        }

        public void setProdDesc(String sSet2) {
            prodDesc = sSet2;
        }

        public void setQuantity(int iSet) {
            quantity = iSet;
        }

        public String getPartNo() { return partNo; }
        public String getProdDesc() { return prodDesc; }
        public int getQuantity() { return quantity; }

        public void showPart() {
            System.out.println("Item#: " + partNo);
            System.out.println("Description: " + prodDesc);
            System.out.println("Quantity: " + quantity);
        }

        showPart();
    }
}
```

The errors it's giving me don't really make a whole lot of sense to me. What am I doing wrong?

```
File: M:\Intro to Software\InventoryFinal.java  [line: 8]
Error: Syntax error on token "public", new expected
File: M:\Intro to Software\InventoryFinal.java  [line: 8]
Error: Syntax error on token "{", { expected after this token
File: M:\Intro to Software\InventoryFinal.java  [line: 42]
Error: Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
File: M:\Intro to Software\InventoryFinal.java  [line: 42]
Error: Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
```

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I copied and pasted straight from DrJava.

Comment: It looks to me like `InventoryFinal` declares a main method, then tries to define classes and instance variables inside the main method.  I.e., you forgot to close the main method with a closing brace.

Comment: Hint: whenever you get "weird errors" like this, look carefully at the first line of the error, then look **up** in the file to make sure everything before that point is as it should be.  Stuff like forgetting a brace or semicolon is pretty common, even for experienced programmerns.

Comment: Nothing weird here -- this isn't valid Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not have embedded methods.  At the moment you have all fields and methods inside your main method

it should be more like

```
public class InventoryFinal {

    String partNo;
    String prodDesc;
    int quantity;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create new instances and call methods from here
    }

    public InventoryFinal() {
        partNo = "AA0000";
        prodDesc = "Test Item";
        quantity = 0;
    }

    public InventoryFinal(String s, String s2, int i) {
        partNo = s;
        prodDesc = s2;
        quantity = i;
    }

    public void setPartNo(String sSet) {
        partNo = sSet;
    }

    public void setProdDesc(String sSet2) {
        prodDesc = sSet2;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int iSet) {
        quantity = iSet;
    }

} // close class
```